# Is C++ Edit and Continue functionality available for anything other than VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Does Eclipse or other IDE's support Edit and Continue for C++?

Comment: love this feature of visual studio

Answer (score 3):

You mean the debugger feature ?
It's more a debugger-dependent than an IDE-dependent feature.

When using Eclipse, my debugger back-end is gdb, so yes, it does support Edit&Continue. (even if it's a bit odd to use, see `info -f gdb -n Patching`)